# MySQL - Java syntax error. Why this doesnt work?

Tags: java, mysql, variables

The error line is highlited near "BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), interval " + days + " day) AND current_date()" but this statement work on the mysql  workbench. '
So, maybe the mistake is on the way of using between or the date in that way.
The thing im trying to do is filter the data considering my actual date and the days before that i introduce throught the variable days in "date_sub(now(), interval **here the days** days)" .
Is there a correct or more efficient way?

```
private void getStatement(int days) {
    try {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.jtblReports.setModel(model);
        Connection con = this.connection.getConexion();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String SELECT = "SELECT client_name, client_surname, client_dni,"
                + " game_name, rent_date, return_date, game_price from "
                + "rent_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), interval " + days + " day) AND current_date()";

        ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsCant = rsMd.getColumnCount();

        model.addColumn("CLIENT NAME");
        model.addColumn("CLIENT SURNAME");
        model.addColumn("CLIENT DNI");
        model.addColumn("GAME");
        model.addColumn("RENT DATE");
        model.addColumn("RETURN DATE");
        model.addColumn("GAME PRICE");

        while (rs.next()) {

            Object[] rows = new Object[columnsCant];

            for (int i = 0; i < columnsCant; i++) {
                rows[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            model.addRow(rows);

        }

        model.fireTableDataChanged();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: post totel code with error.

Comment: the error is "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), interval 7 day) AND current_date()' at line 1"

Comment: Where's your Table name in your query?

Comment: that was the error! thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is missing at least the name of the table and the start of the WHERE clause, it should look more like this:

SELECT ... FROM **your_table WHERE** rent_date BETWEEN ...